# Merge arrays with matching string values and increment the numbers

Tags: php

My app gets API responses in this format, where the first x elements are string labels, and the following numerical. The number of string labels and numerical elements can vary per API response, but not within a response.

I'd like to merge these together, so that the rows with the same string labels get their numerical values summed.

Before:

```
Array(
  Array('one', 'two', 'three', 1, 2),
  Array('one', 'two', 'three', 1, 4),
  Array('one', 'six', 'three', 2, 5),
  Array('one', 'two', 'seven', 5, 9),
  Array('one', 'six', 'three', 6, 1)
)
```

After:

```
Array(
  Array('one', 'two', 'three', 2, 6),
  Array('one', 'six', 'three', 8, 6),
  Array('one', 'two', 'seven', 5, 9)
)
```

What would be an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array_values(
    array_reduce($array, function (array $result, array $item) {
        $key = serialize(array_filter($item, 'is_string'));

        if (!isset($result[$key])) {
            $result[$key] = $item;
        } else {
            $result[$key] = array_map(
                function ($a, $b) { return is_int($a) ? $a + $b : $a; },
                $result[$key],
                $item
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }, [])
);
```

Your data is expected to be in `$array`.

The key, literally, is to simply generate a unique identifier for each array which you can use to deduplicate; this is done by serialising all string values here. Then you can simply sum all the integers in duplicates while leaving the strings alone, which is done with an `array_map`. The `array_values` wrapper then just gets rid of the generated keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, it doesn't seem very clear, but if you need that could be useful:

```
function summarizeArr($arr,$num) {
    $newArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $row) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($newArr as &$newRow) {
            $ok = true;
            for ($i=0 ; $i<$num; $i++) {
                if ($row[$i] != $newRow[$i]) {
                    $ok = false;
                    continue ;
                }
            }
            if (!$ok) continue;
            for ($i=$num; $i<count($row); $i++) {
                $newRow[$i] = $newRow[$i]+$row[$i];

            }
            $found=true;
            break;
        }
        if (!$found) $newArr[] = $row;
    }
    return $newArr;
}
$arr = Array(
  Array('one', 'two', 'three', 1, 2),
  Array('one', 'two', 'three', 1, 4),
  Array('one', 'six', 'three', 2, 5),
  Array('one', 'two', 'seven', 5, 9),
  Array('one', 'six', 'three', 6, 1)
);

print_r (summarizeArr($arr,3));
```